# Failed to enable unit: Invalid argument systemctl enable .service

Tags: linux, command-line, boot, terminal, systemd

I have made a startup_test.sh with the following contents

```
cd /home/xyz/Desktop/
gnome-terminal -e "bash -c ./efg"
```

---

#desktop folder contains an executable named `efg`.

If I run `gnome-terminal -e "bash -c ./efg"` in terminal it just works fine. Opens a new terminal and program `efg` is running correctly.I want to make this script `startup_test.sh` run after bootup/login.

---

I am in a login which has root privileges.

```
chmod +x startup_test.sh
cp startup_test.sh /usr/sbin/
```

My `startup_test.service` has the following contents:

```
[Unit]
Description=ABC
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/startup_test.sh
WorkingDirectory=/home/xyz/Desktop/startup
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=%n
```

`startup_test.service` is placed in `/etc/systemd/system` folder.

Now the command

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

is run.
No output.

Now the command `systemctl enable startup_test.service` is giving the following output:

```
Failed to enable unit : Invalid argument
```

What is the cause of the above output.

the command `systemctl start startup_test.service` is giving no output.

The command `systemctl status startup_test.service` is giving:

```
startup_test.service - ABC
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/startup_test.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2024-02-19 12:09:20 IST; 2min 55s ago
  Process: 32531 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/startup_test.sh (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
 Main PID: 32531 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Feb 19 12:09:20 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started ABC.
Feb 19 12:09:20 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: startup_test.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Feb 19 12:09:20 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: startup_test.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

OS is redhat 8.2